Vector product and normal of a surface
In a certain exercise I have been asked to show the following identity:
$N(u,v) \times \phi_u(u,v) = \frac{E(u,v)\phi_v(u,v)-F(u,v)\phi_u(u,v)}{\sqrt{EG-F^2}}$, where $N(u,v)$ is the normal vector of the surface $S$ parametrized by $\phi(u,v)$ and with first fundamental form of coefficients $E,F,G$. I really don't know how to start. The only thing I know here is that $N(u,v) = \phi_u(u,v) \times \phi_v(u,v)$ but the appearence of three cross products seems to show that that isn't the right way. I would be grateful if somebody could give me a hint.

On the left you have two cross products linking three vectors:
$$
N(u,v) \times \phi_u(u,v) = 
(\phi_u(u,v) \times \phi_v(u,v)) \times \phi_u(u,v)
$$
which can be computed using Lagrange's formula to be
$$ \left<\phi_u(u,v), \phi_u(u,v) \right>\phi_v(u,v) - \left<\phi_u(u,v), \phi_v(u,v) \right>\phi_u(u,v).$$
This basically gives the answer, mod some normalization

I didn't even know about that formula, or at least I had never used. Now it is much clearer, thanks.
